# Mule HTTP Listener Thread Can't Resolve org.glassfish.grizzly.localization.LogMessages

Tags: mule

I have a mule app with Mule EE 3.8.0 which has it's http listener configured with worker threading profile to throttle the request traffic

Sample as below

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
    host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration">
    <http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="10" 
        threadWaitTimeout="15000" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>

</http:listener-config>
```

This app is functioning well, but in logs there are increasing numbers of errors as below:

ERROR 2016-11-24 17:02:00,813 [[mule-api-v1].http.listener(2) SelectorRunner] org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner: doSelect exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.grizzly.localization.LogMessages
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:90) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:75) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:415) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:384) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:348) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573) ~[grizzly-core-2.3.28.jar:2.3.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]

Exception in thread "[mule--api-v1].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.grizzly.localization.LogMessages
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception in thread "[mule-api-v1].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.02" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.grizzly.localization.LogMessages
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception in thread "[mule-api-v1].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.03" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.grizzly.localization.LogMessages
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

.... and so on and so on ....

As above stack trace shows, the number in the thread name such as `HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.03` increases with every request this listener receives.

If I remove the work-threading-profile block, this issue is disappeared, but it is a must have to us, so please help anyone if you can point me a work around to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mule EE you should create a support case in [MuleSoft Support Center](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/login/)

Comment: This is poor advice, why not solve the problem here? Otherwise outline *why* this is a case of mule not behaving the way it should, therefore requiring a mule support ticket?

Comment: I'm not sure but this could be related to https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-11337
Since he is already a customer he will have access to Customer Support from MuleSoft and receive a bug fix. For full disclosure, I actually work at MuleSoft Support.

Comment: @Mooz your point makes sense, however, Mule does expect ticket with questions if it's EE related. I did the support case and Mule replied a patch in jar file last week. I haven't fully tested it though.